# How can I select just the first X characters from a text column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

On my PostgreSQL DB I have a table that looks like below. The description column can store a string of any size.

What I'm looking for, is a way to select just the first X chars from the content of the description column, or the whole string if X > description.length

```
CREATE TABLE descriptions (
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    description text NULL,
);
```

E.g.: If X = 100 chars and if in the description column I store a string containing 150+ chars, when I run `select <some method on description> from descriptions`, I just want to get back the first 100 chars from the description column.

Bonus if the approach proposed is extremely fast!

Comment: I can create a second column to store the short version, but I don't feel like duplicating data

Answer (score 3):

Use a [type cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) or use [`substring()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-string.html):

```
SELECT CAST(description AS varchar(100)), substring(description for 100)
FROM descriptions;
```

Or if you want to do it the "PostgreSQL way":

```
SELECT description::varchar(100), substr(description, 1, 100)
FROM descriptions;
```